# How to make a horizontal thumbnail scrollable carausel in Vue?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to replicate this sort of a thumbnail container which is horizontal scrollable.

[image]

I have a `GARMENTS` button in my Vue.js Code that returns thumbnails as follows.

[image]

I am getting my thumbnails from the firebase storage and I want the carousel to look more like the first image with the horizontal scroll. What should I add to make it like so?

Here is the code for the `Buttons` Component:

```
<template>
<div class="gallery-container gallery-garments hide">
    <div v-for="gar in allGarments" :key="gar.id" class="gallery-item">
        <img :src="getImgUrl(gar.thumbnailLink)" height="150" width="100">
        <span style="display:block">{{gar.name}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
    <v-btn color="primary" v-on:click="toggleGallery('garments')">Garments</v-btn>
    <v-btn>Templates</v-btn>
    <v-btn>Download</v-btn>
    <v-btn>Share</v-btn>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "Buttons",
    data () {
        return {
            garments: [],
        }
    },
    methods: {
        toggleGallery(type) {
            document.querySelectorAll(".gallery-container").forEach(el => {
                if (!el.classList.contains(`gallery-${type}`)) {
                    el.classList.add("hide")    
                }
            })
            document.querySelector(`.gallery-${type}`).classList.toggle("hide")
        },
        getImgUrl(url){ return url; }
    }
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS, a good start would be:

```
.gallery-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Demo:

```css
.gallery-item {
  display: inline-block;
}

.gallery-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 200px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-container gallery-garments hide">
    <div class="gallery-item">
        <img src="" height="150" width="100">
        <span style="display:block">Name</span>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-item">
        <img src="" height="150" width="100">
        <span style="display:block">Name</span>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-item">
        <img src="" height="150" width="100">
        <span style="display:block">Name</span>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-item">
        <img src="" height="150" width="100">
        <span style="display:block">Name</span>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-item">
        <img src="" height="150" width="100">
        <span style="display:block">Name</span>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-item">
        <img src="" height="150" width="100">
        <span style="display:block">Name</span>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-item">
        <img src="" height="150" width="100">
        <span style="display:block">Name</span>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-item">
        <img src="" height="150" width="100">
        <span style="display:block">Name</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for answer. But how can I get a horizontal slider there?